# Repeated measures design with measurements from different groups of animals

Tags: r, time-series, anova, repeated-measures, generalized-estimating-equations

In a repeated measured design we measure a particular variable at different time points from the same subjects. In animal experiments, if animals are sacrificed at every time point to measure a variable, theoretically the measurements at every time point are from different animals, though the measured variable is same. Can such experiment setting be called repeated measure design ?

Answer (score 0):

With a little introduction, the answer to your question will be clear.  One important, potential benefit of a repeated measures design is reduction of error variance, since two or more measures are taken on the same subjects, say at repeated time intervals.  The between-subject variability (e.g., due to age, height, weight, intelligence) is largely taken out of the data when the statistical analysis reflects the within-subect design.  The design you describe is a between-subject design.